# Is undefined variable equal to nil in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I got error as `undefined variable`, I know `nil` is evaluated to `false` if used as boolean:

```
if y
  puts "Something"
end
```

Comment: both both answers are correct,check this for more details on this topic http://www.rubyist.net/~slagell/ruby/localvars.html

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Undefined variable is not equal to nil.

Undefined **instance** variable returns nil (again, if it is undefined).

`y` raises an exception

`@y` returns nil

Answer (score 11):

No, you'll get an error `undefined local variable or method`. But if you want to check whether something is defined or not, you can use `defined?` method like this

```
if defined?(my_var)
  print 'defined'
else
  print 'not defined'
end
```

Answer (score 6):

There's a slight wrinkle on this.  Try this:

```
if 5 == 0
   y = 'hi'
end

puts "hello" if y
```

`y` has been "defined" in the `if` block.  Remove that block and this gives an error.